# IMDB get movie/show poster by title

Tags: media-queries, imdb

using IMDB or any other media resource is it possible to get movie/shows/programs poster image  and in bast case scenario more information. by passing their title to their restful api ?

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

poster url can be found from imdb json url

http://www.imdbapi.com/?i=&t=glee